# Integer value in text file not changing

Tags: python

I have a function that retrieves the current value of what's in the text file, and then at the end of my program I have it increment the value by 1. However, the value is not always increased. What could be the cause?

**Get the var value**

```
def get_var_value(filename="varstore.dat"):
    with open(filename, "r+") as f:
        val = int(f.read() or 0)
        f.seek(0)
        f.truncate()
        return val
```

**Increment the value by 1:**

```
def increase_var_value(filename="varstore.dat"):
    with open(filename, "r+") as f:
        val = int(f.read() or 0) +1
        f.seek(0)
        f.truncate()
        f.write(str(val))
        return val
```

Comment: When does the value not increase? Does it not increase after the 1st call or randomly? And also how are you calling the 2 functions and how many times?

Comment: you have to open the file in write mode: `with open(filename, "rw") as f:` and then it will work

Comment: the `get_var_value` is removing file content, @Reez0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `get_var_value`function does not need to seek and truncate the file. Its deleting the contents of the file befor the `increment_var_value` reads it. Due to this the `increment_var_value` always reads it as 0 and then increments it by 1 and hence the value is always 1.

The code will now be,

```
def get_var_value(filename="varstore.dat"):
    with open(filename, "r") as f:
        val = int(f.read() or 0)
        return val


def increase_var_value(filename="varstore.dat"):
    with open(filename, "r+") as f:
        val = int(f.read() or 0) + 1
        f.seek(0)
        f.truncate()
        f.write(str(val))
        return val
```